# Need to show a button in pagelayout with Login AS User

Tags: apex, visualforce, login

I want a button on the Opportunity Page Layout: <kbd>Login As User</kbd>.

The User which needs to login is only one particular user. When I click <kbd>Login As User</kbd> button its needs to be logged in as that user.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Can you elaborate on your business requirement?

Comment: I just wanted a button in opp standard Layout with Login As User(like the standard functionality in Salesforce User Interface).The requiremne is if perticular User open the Opp Record and he wants to see somthing woth the other users record,he can directly login from cliking the bitton in record.I am not able to understand how can i proceed.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at these links in the `User` tab, you will see the Login link addresses look like:

> `https://<instance>.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.su?oid=00D...&suorgadminid=005...&retURL=...&targetURL=...`

So, copy this value into a new `Custom Button` with a `Content Source` of `URL`. If you copy this link address for the user you want to log in as, you would only need to change the `retURL` and `targetURL` to make the button usable. The URL would look something like:

```
https://cs1.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.su?
oid=00D000000000000
&suorgadminid=005000000000000
&retURL=%2F{!Opportunity.Id}
&targetURL=%2F{!Opportunity.Id}
```

Note that it will be a bit more work to make a button URL that works across all environments. You should also make sure to create a separate Page Layout for the users who should have access to this button. Most of your users shouldn't have the required permissions.